# Update stuck at "Configuring locales"

Tags: apt, updates, locale

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.10 and installed proprietary drivers. Then I ran ordinary update of packages and there were tons of them (over 200 MB). However, the update is stuck at "Configuring locales" and the "console" area shows `Setting up locales (2.24-3ubuntu2) ...`. See the screenshot.

Is there anything I can do about it (i.e. get out of the stuck state) and not break the package(s) at the same time?

[image: Setting up locales]

The whole log:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 158419 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tar_1.29b-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tar (1.29b-1ubuntu0.1) over (1.29b-1) ...
Setting up tar (1.29b-1ubuntu0.1) ...
(Reading database ... 158419 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-locales_2.24-3ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking locales (2.24-3ubuntu2) over (2.24-3ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-libc-bin_2.24-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-bin (2.24-3ubuntu2) over (2.24-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libc-bin (2.24-3ubuntu2) ...
(Reading database ... 158419 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-xserver-common_2%3a1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-common (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1) over (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-libsystemd0_231-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsystemd0:amd64 (231-9ubuntu1) over (231-9git1) ...
Setting up libsystemd0:amd64 (231-9ubuntu1) ...
(Reading database ... 158419 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-xserver-xorg-core_2%3a1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-core (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1) over (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-libnss-resolve_231-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnss-resolve:amd64 (231-9ubuntu1) over (231-9git1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-libpam-systemd_231-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-systemd:amd64 (231-9ubuntu1) over (231-9git1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-libnss-myhostname_231-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnss-myhostname:amd64 (231-9ubuntu1) over (231-9git1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-ifupdown_0.8.13ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ifupdown (0.8.13ubuntu3) over (0.8.13ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-systemd_231-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (231-9ubuntu1) over (231-9git1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../6-udev_231-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (231-9ubuntu1) over (231-9git1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-libudev1_231-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libudev1:amd64 (231-9ubuntu1) over (231-9git1) ...
Setting up libudev1:amd64 (231-9ubuntu1) ...
(Reading database ... 158419 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libapparmor1_2.10.95-4ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapparmor1:amd64 (2.10.95-4ubuntu5.1) over (2.10.95-4ubuntu5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-dbus-user-session_1.10.10-1ubuntu1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dbus-user-session (1.10.10-1ubuntu1.1) over (1.10.10-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-dbus-x11_1.10.10-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dbus-x11 (1.10.10-1ubuntu1.1) over (1.10.10-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-libdbus-1-3_1.10.10-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdbus-1-3:amd64 (1.10.10-1ubuntu1.1) over (1.10.10-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-dbus_1.10.10-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dbus (1.10.10-1ubuntu1.1) over (1.10.10-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libapparmor1:amd64 (2.10.95-4ubuntu5.1) ...
Setting up systemd (231-9ubuntu1) ...
addgroup: The group `systemd-journal' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
(Reading database ... 158419 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-systemd-sysv_231-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-sysv (231-9ubuntu1) over (231-9git1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-libmagickwand-6.q16-2_8%3a6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2) over (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-libmagickcore-6.q16-2_8%3a6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2) over (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-imagemagick-common_8%3a6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking imagemagick-common (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2) over (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libreofficekit-data_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreofficekit-data (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libreoffice-calc_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-calc (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libreoffice-impress_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-impress (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libreoffice-draw_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-draw (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libreoffice-gnome_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-gnome (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libreoffice-writer_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-writer (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-uno-libs3_5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking uno-libs3 (5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-libreoffice-ogltrans_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-ogltrans (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-ure_5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ure (5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-python3-uno_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-uno (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-libreoffice-style-tango_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-style-tango (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-libreoffice-style-elementary_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-style-elementary (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-libreoffice-common_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-libreoffice-pdfimport_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-pdfimport (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-libreoffice-math_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-math (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../19-gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1 (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../20-liblibreofficekitgtk_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblibreofficekitgtk (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../21-libreoffice-gtk3_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-gtk3 (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../22-libreoffice-base-core_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-base-core (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../23-libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../24-libreoffice-core_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-core (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../25-libreoffice-style-galaxy_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-style-galaxy (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../26-fonts-opensymbol_2%3a102.7+LibO5.2.2-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-opensymbol (2:102.7+LibO5.2.2-0ubuntu2) over (2:102.7+LibO5.2.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../27-libcurl3-gnutls_7.50.1-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.50.1-1ubuntu1.1) over (7.50.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../28-multiarch-support_2.24-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking multiarch-support (2.24-3ubuntu2) over (2.24-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up multiarch-support (2.24-3ubuntu2) ...
(Reading database ... 158419 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-tzdata_2016j-0ubuntu0.16.10_all.deb ...
Unpacking tzdata (2016j-0ubuntu0.16.10) over (2016g-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-distro-info-data_0.29ubuntu0.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking distro-info-data (0.29ubuntu0.1) over (0.29) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-libisc-export160_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libisc-export160 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) over (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-libdns-export162_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdns-export162 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) over (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libapparmor-perl_2.10.95-4ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapparmor-perl (2.10.95-4ubuntu5.1) over (2.10.95-4ubuntu5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-apparmor_2.10.95-4ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apparmor (2.10.95-4ubuntu5.1) over (2.10.95-4ubuntu5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-dnsutils_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dnsutils (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) over (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-bind9-host_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bind9-host (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) over (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libisc160_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libisc160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) over (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libdns162_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdns162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) over (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-libisccc140_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libisccc140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) over (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-libisccfg140_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libisccfg140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) over (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-liblwres141_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblwres141:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) over (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-libbind9-140_1%3a9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbind9-140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) over (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk_1%3a16.10.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:16.10.9) over (1:16.10.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-ubuntu-release-upgrader-core_1%3a16.10.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:16.10.9) over (1:16.10.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-python3-distupgrade_1%3a16.10.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distupgrade (1:16.10.9) over (1:16.10.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-tcpdump_4.7.4-1ubuntu1.16.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tcpdump (4.7.4-1ubuntu1.16.10.1) over (4.7.4-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-libevolution_3.22.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevolution (3.22.1-0ubuntu2) over (3.22.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../19-evolution-plugins_3.22.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking evolution-plugins (3.22.1-0ubuntu2) over (3.22.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../20-evolution_3.22.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking evolution (3.22.1-0ubuntu2) over (3.22.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../21-evolution-common_3.22.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking evolution-common (3.22.1-0ubuntu2) over (3.22.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../22-nautilus-data_1%3a3.20.3-1ubuntu3.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nautilus-data (1:3.20.3-1ubuntu3.1) over (1:3.20.3-1ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../23-nautilus_1%3a3.20.3-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nautilus (1:3.20.3-1ubuntu3.1) over (1:3.20.3-1ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../24-libnautilus-extension1a_1%3a3.20.3-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (1:3.20.3-1ubuntu3.1) over (1:3.20.3-1ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../25-file-roller_3.22.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking file-roller (3.22.1-0ubuntu1) over (3.22.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../26-libgtk2.0-common_2.24.30-4ubuntu3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk2.0-common (2.24.30-4ubuntu3) over (2.24.30-4ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../27-gtk2-engines-pixbuf_2.24.30-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gtk2-engines-pixbuf:amd64 (2.24.30-4ubuntu3) over (2.24.30-4ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../28-libgtk2.0-bin_2.24.30-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk2.0-bin (2.24.30-4ubuntu3) over (2.24.30-4ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../29-libgail-common_2.24.30-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgail-common:amd64 (2.24.30-4ubuntu3) over (2.24.30-4ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../30-libgail18_2.24.30-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgail18:amd64 (2.24.30-4ubuntu3) over (2.24.30-4ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../31-libgtk2.0-0_2.24.30-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (2.24.30-4ubuntu3) over (2.24.30-4ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../32-firefox_50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox (50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) over (49.0+build4-0ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../33-firefox-locale-en_50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox-locale-en (50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) over (49.0+build4-0ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../34-ghostscript-x_9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ghostscript-x (9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6.3) over (9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../35-ghostscript_9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ghostscript (9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6.3) over (9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../36-libgs9_9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgs9:amd64 (9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6.3) over (9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../37-libgs9-common_9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgs9-common (9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6.3) over (9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../38-gnome-settings-daemon_3.22.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-settings-daemon (3.22.1-0ubuntu1) over (3.22.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../39-gnome-settings-daemon-schemas_3.22.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (3.22.1-0ubuntu1) over (3.22.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../40-libpulsedsp_1%3a9.0-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:9.0-2ubuntu2.1) over (1:9.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../41-pulseaudio-utils_1%3a9.0-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio-utils (1:9.0-2ubuntu2.1) over (1:9.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../42-pulseaudio-module-bluetooth_1%3a9.0-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (1:9.0-2ubuntu2.1) over (1:9.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../43-pulseaudio_1%3a9.0-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio (1:9.0-2ubuntu2.1) over (1:9.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../44-libpulse-mainloop-glib0_1%3a9.0-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:9.0-2ubuntu2.1) over (1:9.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../45-libpulse0_1%3a9.0-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpulse0:amd64 (1:9.0-2ubuntu2.1) over (1:9.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../46-gnome-control-center-data_1%3a3.20.2-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-control-center-data (1:3.20.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:3.20.1-2ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../47-gnome-control-center_1%3a3.20.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-control-center (1:3.20.2-0ubuntu2) over (1:3.20.1-2ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../48-gnome-shell_3.20.4-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-shell (3.20.4-0ubuntu2) over (3.20.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../49-gnome-shell-common_3.20.4-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-shell-common (3.20.4-0ubuntu2) over (3.20.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../50-gnome-software_3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-software (3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2) over (3.20.1+git20161003.0.7ac7d1b-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../51-gnome-software-common_3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-software-common (3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2) over (3.20.1+git20161003.0.7ac7d1b-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsnapd-glib1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../52-libsnapd-glib1_1.2-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsnapd-glib1:amd64 (1.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../53-gstreamer1.0-plugins-good_1.8.3-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu1.2) over (1.8.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../54-libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0_1.8.3-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu1.2) over (1.8.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../55-gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio_1.8.3-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu1.2) over (1.8.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../56-im-config_0.29-1ubuntu16.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking im-config (0.29-1ubuntu16.1) over (0.29-1ubuntu16) ...
Preparing to unpack .../57-imagemagick_8%3a6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking imagemagick (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2) over (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8) ...
Preparing to unpack .../58-imagemagick-6.q16_8%3a6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking imagemagick-6.q16 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2) over (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8) ...
Preparing to unpack .../59-libcurl3_7.50.1-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3:amd64 (7.50.1-1ubuntu1.1) over (7.50.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../60-libgd3_2.2.1-1ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgd3:amd64 (2.2.1-1ubuntu3.2) over (2.2.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgspell-1-common.
Preparing to unpack .../61-libgspell-1-common_1.0.3-1ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgspell-1-common (1.0.3-1ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../62-libgspell-1-1_1.0.3-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgspell-1-1:amd64 (1.0.3-1ubuntu4) over (1.0.3-1ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../63-libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra_8%3a6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2) over (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.8.0-30-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../64-linux-image-4.8.0-30-generic_4.8.0-30.32_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.8.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-30-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.8.0-30-generic (4.8.0-30.32) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-30-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../65-linux-image-extra-4.8.0-30-generic_4.8.0-30.32_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-extra-4.8.0-30-generic (4.8.0-30.32) ...
Preparing to unpack .../66-linux-generic_4.8.0.30.39_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (4.8.0.30.39) over (4.8.0.22.31) ...
Preparing to unpack .../67-linux-image-generic_4.8.0.30.39_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (4.8.0.30.39) over (4.8.0.22.31) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-signed-image-4.8.0-30-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../68-linux-signed-image-4.8.0-30-generic_4.8.0-30.32_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-signed-image-4.8.0-30-generic (4.8.0-30.32) ...
Preparing to unpack .../69-linux-signed-generic_4.8.0.30.39_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-signed-generic (4.8.0.30.39) over (4.8.0.22.31) ...
Preparing to unpack .../70-linux-signed-image-generic_4.8.0.30.39_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-signed-image-generic (4.8.0.30.39) over (4.8.0.22.31) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.8.0-30.
Preparing to unpack .../71-linux-headers-4.8.0-30_4.8.0-30.32_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.8.0-30 (4.8.0-30.32) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.8.0-30-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../72-linux-headers-4.8.0-30-generic_4.8.0-30.32_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.8.0-30-generic (4.8.0-30.32) ...
Preparing to unpack .../73-linux-headers-generic_4.8.0.30.39_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.8.0.30.39) over (4.8.0.22.31) ...
Preparing to unpack .../74-python-cryptography_1.5-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-cryptography (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) over (1.5-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../75-python3-cryptography_1.5-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-cryptography (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) over (1.5-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../76-snapd_2.16+16.10ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Warning: Stopping snapd.service, but it can still be activated by:
  snapd.socket
Unpacking snapd (2.16+16.10ubuntu1.2) over (2.16+16.10ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package snapd-login-service.
Preparing to unpack .../77-snapd-login-service_1.2-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd-login-service (1.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../78-unattended-upgrades_0.92ubuntu1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking unattended-upgrades (0.92ubuntu1.1) over (0.92ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../79-xserver-xephyr_2%3a1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xephyr (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1) over (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../80-xwayland_2%3a1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xwayland (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1) over (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libgs9-common (9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6.3) ...
Setting up python3-cryptography (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (3.22.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gnome-software-common (3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up xserver-common (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1) ...
Setting up libgtk2.0-common (2.24.30-4ubuntu3) ...
Setting up evolution-common (3.22.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up firefox-locale-en (50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) ...
Setting up libisc160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up ifupdown (0.8.13ubuntu3) ...
Setting up im-config (0.29-1ubuntu16.1) ...
Setting up nautilus-data (1:3.20.3-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libisc-export160 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libnss-myhostname:amd64 (231-9ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libcurl3:amd64 (7.50.1-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.50.1-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up tzdata (2016j-0ubuntu0.16.10) ...

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Prague'
Local time is now:      Sun Dec 11 00:11:49 CET 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Sat Dec 10 23:11:49 UTC 2016.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

Setting up systemd-sysv (231-9ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.50.0-1) ...
Setting up libdns-export162 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libgd3:amd64 (2.2.1-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up imagemagick-common (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2) ...
Setting up distro-info-data (0.29ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up xserver-xephyr (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-2) ...
Setting up libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu8.2) ...
Setting up tcpdump (4.7.4-1ubuntu1.16.10.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump ...
Setting up gnome-shell-common (3.20.4-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up snapd (2.16+16.10ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libgspell-1-common (1.0.3-1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up gnome-control-center-data (1:3.20.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libisccc140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libsnapd-glib1:amd64 (1.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.8.0-30 (4.8.0-30.32) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up udev (231-9ubuntu1) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (1:3.20.3-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (231-9ubuntu1) ...
Setting up liblwres141:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up python-cryptography (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.92ubuntu1.1) ...
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/Stack.pm line 111, <GEN0> line 12.
Replacing config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades with new version
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Use of uninitialized value $val in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 83, <GEN7> line 12.
Use of uninitialized value $val in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 84, <GEN7> line 12.
Setting up snapd-login-service (1.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libnss-resolve:amd64 (231-9ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.7-1) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.8.0-30-generic (4.8.0-30.32) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-30-generic
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-30-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-30-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.8.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.8.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.8.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-30-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-22-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Setting up xwayland (2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu4) ...
Setting up fonts-opensymbol (2:102.7+LibO5.2.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up uno-libs3 (5.2.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Setting up libgs9:amd64 (9.19~dfsg+1-0ubuntu6.3) ...
Setting up locales (2.24-3ubuntu2) ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it's stuck it's stuck... Personally I'd interrupt the process by closing the window. Then I'd open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+T) and first try:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall locales
```

and then, if it succeeds, continue with

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Not exactly what I did but in the essence it was the same. Thanks.